# How to ignore DTD in Hive XPath?

Tags: hadoop, xpath, hive

How do I ensure that Hive ignores the DTD?

The following works in Hive:

```
select xpath_string('<a><b>bb</b><c>cc</c></a>', 'a/b') from src limit 1;
```

But this query doesn't (added DTD):

```
select xpath_string('<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-archivearticle1.dtd"><a><b>bb</b><c>cc</c></a>', 'a/b') from src limit 1;
```

Which fails with this error:

```
Error occurred executing hive query: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''a/b'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public org.apache.hadoop.io.Text org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathString.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathString@70b25313 of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.xml.UDFXPathString with arguments {<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-archivearticle1.dtd"><a><b>bb</b><c>cc</c></a>:java.lang.String, a/b:java.lang.String} of size 2
```

Comment: Well handling DTD is more of an Xpath issue rather than Hive UDF. For xpath_string, no information is found regarding handling DTD. One option could be to remove DTD and then use the xml. I know its not a feasible answer.

Comment: @Ramzy yes that's what I'm going for right now, but I'm using other tools for that (Spark). I wish there was a simpler way

Comment: dont forget to post answer, if you found one

Comment: @Ramzy - it's a workaround that doesn't involve XPath or Hive. I don't think that'd be a good answer